# Mini-Mobile And Mobile Tripods - How To Make Them Hold Smartphones For Taking Good Still Shots?

Tags: tripod, tripod-socket, gorillapod

I am mostly taking shots with my HTC Desire S 5MP smartphone.

But for a long time wanted to get mobile tripod which is compact and easy to carry. The problem is with their mostly used **universal 1/4 screw** which is only good for point&shoot and bridge cameras. Of course there are very few mobile tripods with special mount holders for cellphones like this one from DX for example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cddwm.jpg

There are others which are better however with the sole problem of mount holder being abscent and only universal 1/4 screw is what they have. There is one I've found on TD like this 51-65mm spring clip clamp with 1/4 screw mount socket for GPS, cellphones and camcorders:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia2dH.jpg

Did anyone try such item? I also want to get Gorillapod-like tripod which is obviously cheaper version made in China, but questions I wanted to ask you guys are does anyone of you already have such tripods? And if you do, can you enlighten me about them and tell your experience with such gadgets?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For iPhone only: http://www.canopyco.com/Kapok

Answer (score 1):

I use a mount called the Glif for my iPhone. It is essentially a small holder for the phone that has a standard tripod mount on the bottom of it. You can see more of it here [Glif website](http://www.studioneat.com/products/glif-for-iphone-4). 
I think your best option is to get any adapter that is designed specifically for your phone and that adds a 1/4 mount for a standard tripod.
[image]

Comment: Glif is for iPhone but I have found 2 holders that fit my device.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this in the past by using a [ram-mount](http://www.rammount.com/) adapter that I had for my motorcycle in conjunction with my DSLR gorilla-pod. The ball joints work great together and it's one of the most sturdy setups you can have. I did this for video before I got my GoPro.

This is a pricier route, but these things can take a beating. I've used the ram-mount on my motorcycle for years and it will not let go of the phone and even protects it pretty well (we use them in the military also). They make a wide variety of phone holders so they should have some good options.